# Is there a way where i can obtain the number of login attempts from expo local authentication's fingerprint prompt?

Tags: react-native, expo, android-biometric-prompt

I am trying to implement a screen lock after a certain number of failed attempts and this requires tracking of the number of biometric attempts in the application. I understand that expo local authentication will return result.error === "lockout" for too many failed attempts.

However, can i get the specific number of attempts or customise the maximum number of attempts with expo local authentication?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt#ERROR_LOCKOUT() seems to imply the number of failed attempt is hardcoded to 5 times